# CSS display:block not doing anything

Tags: html, css

I am trying to display links as blocks using CSS, however, it is not working. The HTML code should be fine, in my opinion the issue lies in the CSS.

```css
#header {
  overflow: hidden;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  padding: 10px 100px;
  font-size: 14px;
  background: #efefef;
  color: black;
}

#header .logo {
  float: left;
  margin-right: 5%;
}

#header ul.menu {
  list-style: none;
}

#header ul.menu li {
  float: left;
  padding: 4px 10px;
}

#header ul.menu li.selected a,
#header ul.menu li.selected a:hover {
  color: deepskyblue;
  font-weight: bold;
}

#header a {
  color: #f49000;
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
}

#header a:hover {
  color: #fff;
}

#header .user {
  float: right;
  padding-top: 4px;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<div id="header">
  {% if request.user.is_authenticated %}
  <ul class="menu">
    <li {% if section=="dashboard" %}class="selected" {% endif %}>
      <a href="{% url " dashboard " %}">My dashboard</a>
    </li>
    <li {% if section=="home" %}class="selected" {% endif %}>
      <a href="{% url " home " %}">Feed</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
  {% endif %}
</div>
```

The links remain simple text links without any blocks.

How can I get said blocks to be displayed?

Comment: Are you trying to show each links in a line? Coz, currently the `a` is block, but if you are trying to make them 100% width, then you may consider the `li` as well

Answer (score 1):

I have removed the float from li, and added display block to the same. I hope this is what you are trying to achieve

```css
#header {
  overflow: hidden;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  font-size: 14px;
  background: #efefef;
  color: black;
  position: fixed;
}

.content {
  margin-top: 100px;
  height: 100vh;
}

#header .logo {
  margin-right: 5%;
}

#header ul.menu {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  display: flex;
}

#header ul.menu li {
  padding: 4px 10px;
  display: block;
}

#header ul.menu li.selected a,
#header ul.menu li.selected a:hover {
  color: deepskyblue;
  font-weight: bold;
}

#header a {
  color: #f49000;
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
}

#header a:hover {
  color: #fff;
}

#header .user {
  float: right;
  padding-top: 4px;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<div id="header">
  <ul class="menu">
    <li {% if section=="dashboard" %}class="selected" {% endif %}>
      <a href="{% url " dashboard " %}">My dashboard</a>
    </li>
    <li {% if section=="home" %}class="selected" {% endif %}>
      <a href="{% url " home " %}">Feed</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div class='content'>
content
</div>
```

I have made the header a fixed one, so the content under will be scrollable, while the header will be a fixed one.

#edit3

I have edited the code to look similar with the w3Schools page you have shared.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. No I was trying to go for something like this: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_fixed_menu.asp

Comment: You mean fixed header ?

Comment: No, to have the header look like this. That there are blocks instead of just text links.

Comment: I have edited the code to make it looks similar with the w3schools link you have shared. I actually am not getting what exactly you meant by 'block'

Comment: Try using inline-block instead of block